# Реализация поддоменов

Tags: php

Друзья, интересует такая вещь: на многих сайтах (доменах) можно зарегестрироваться и тогда у тебя(твоей организации) появляется личная страничка - ПОДДОМЕН, где можно размещать личную информацию. Вопрос - какова технология этого в 2х словах ? непонимаю например 2 вещи:

1) ну не руками же они заводят поддомен
2) с помощью чего они узнаюи - передают что на таком поддомене надо вытянуть такую инфу ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Вопрос - какова технология этого в 2х
> словах?

В параметрах домена псевдонимы установить `*.domain.com`, после чего главная страница сайта будет доступна по любому поддомену. Далее написать обработчик(тут в двух словах не описать).

Пару месяцев назад была такая же задача, на реализацию потратил примерно 2 дня.

Comment: Что за обработчик ? обрабатываем query_string ? то есть то что до поддомена вырезаем и извлекаем запросами из бд нужный контент ? я правильно вас понял ?

Comment: Правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще и htaccess применить, вот есть интересный пример:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

При этом если у вас адрес выглядит следующим образом sub.mysite.com, то в корне должна находиться папка sub, в которую и будет перенаправлен ваш запрос.

Это все зависит от того для каких целей будет это использоватся.

Comment: @Ъь_ в том и неудобство что должна быть директория.

Comment: ну я и говорю, смотря для каких целей это нужно.